# Javascript regex matching comma when it's not supposed to

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, google-chrome

I cannot figure out this javascript little oddity that's occurs in Firefox 7.0.1 and Google Chrome 14.0.835.202 (I haven't tested any other versions). Why does `/[+-.]/g` match commas (`,`) in addition to plus signs (`+`), dashes (`-`) and periods (`.`)?

```
// Firebug
>>> "Hello, World++--..".match(/[+-.]/g);
[",", "+", "+", "-", "-", ".", "."]
>>> "Hello, World".match(/[+-.]/g);
[","]

// Chrome Developer Tools:
> "Hello, World++--..".match(/[+-.]/g);
  [",", "+", "+", "-", "-", ".", "."]
> "Hello, World".match(/[+-.]/g);
  [","]
```

Okay, so maybe I need to escape the period (`.`)

```
// Firebug
>>> "Hello, World!".match(/[+-\.]/g);
[","]

// Chrome Developer Tools
> "Hello, World!".match(/[+-\.]/g);
  [","]
```

Nope. But if I change the order of the plus (`+`) and dash (`-`) it stops matching the comma (`,`).

```
// Firebug
>>> "Hello, World".match(/[-+.]/g);
null

// Chrome Developer Tools
> "Hello, World".match(/[-+.]/g);
  null
```

This makes no sense to me. It seems odd that both Firefox and Chrome would share the same regex bug. Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: `It seems odd that both Firefox and Chrome would share the same regex bug.` Exactly. They don't :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `[+\-.]`.

`-` masks a range and must be escaped.

Comment: Just what I was entering. `+-.` matches + through . (+,-.)

Comment: Wow, I should have realized that you could use `-` within square brackets with more than just `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `-` within square brackets between two other characters matches all characters in the range between those characters, inclusive.  So, `+` is `U+002B` and `.` is `U+002E`.  All of the characters in that range would include:

```
+ U+002B
, U+002C
- U+002D
. U+002E
```

That it was matching the 3 characters you included plus one more is just a confusing coincidence.  Your answer is in your question... Move the `-` to be the first character in the square brackets:

```js
/[-+.]/g
```

Alternatively, you can escape the `-`:

```js
/[+\-.]/g
```